# Customize aws lambda time out response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, httpresponse

My aws lambda is configured to timeout after 25 sec.

When timeout is reached, I'm getting 500 error returned back to the caller, without any details: `500 Internal Server Error`

Is there any way to customize the lambda response in case of timeout?

Lambda SAM file:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  coreapibackend:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: src.main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: .
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 3008
      Timeout: 25
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/my_lambda'
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-yyy
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-zzz
      Environment:
        Variables:
          A: B
      Tags:
        Name: my_lambda
      Layers:
        - 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:ggg:layer:git-lambda2:8'
      RuntimeManagementConfig:
        UpdateRuntimeOn: Auto
```

Lambda is accessed via http api gateway, but I'm not sure if that's relevant for the response customization.

Comment: No, there is not. You *can* write your lambda in way that it is aware of its own timeout, aborts the progressing e.g. 0.5s before it would timeout and manually returns an error response.

Comment: If only I could easily do that.. thanks.